# Remote Ubuntu 16.04 server creating partitions

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, remote

Today I got access to a remote server with Ubuntu 16.04, basic installation. As far as I can see I got a small partition with the OS and a very big partition.

Not that experienced with Ubuntu I ask myself whether it is possible to split up that big partition into a software/application part and a data part, remotely and without reinstalling Ubuntu. Is that possible?

Additional information: the server is set-up the following:

```
NAME   FSTYPE  SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda           10.9T
├─sda1           1M
├─sda2 ext2    477M /boot
├─sda3 swap    3.8G [SWAP]
├─sda4 ext4    3.8G /tmp
└─sda5 ext4   10.9T /
```

My idea is to have diskspace for installing software (like Talend, R-studio et cetera) and two separate parts, one for data(bases) and one for big data (hdfs). But I have no clue to get this done....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong. `/boot` is part of the OS, but not the whole OS. The other big partition has the rest of the OS as well as applications. In Ubuntu (Linux in general) the OS and the applications are more closely integrated than in Windows. Thus, it is not practical to have one partition for the OS and another for the software.

Comment: @user68186: thanks, so the sda5 part is the part to work with as far as I can see. But reading the url of karel I understand that dividing this partition only can be done with "...Boot to a LiveCD or LiveUSB drive...". I have no clue to perform this from the command line accessing the remote Ubuntu server?

Comment: that `/boot` partition is going to get full and cause problems. You should increase the size of it if possible

Comment: After some over-thinking the issue we have decided to add some extra disk(s) which can be formatted the right way and then mounted to the Ubuntu system. That solves my question, but do I read something about a too small boot-section as Zanna stated?